# Mac OSX restart from command line and close all windows

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, shell

I want to use command line to restart my mac OSX, I'm using:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

But i want to restart **without the reopen windows option**, I've looked at the documentation  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/shutdown.8.html) but with no luck, Any idea?

Comment: There's an excellent QA on Ask Different - but I don't see a 'no reopen' solution - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103571/using-the-terminal-command-to-shutdown-restart-and-sleep-my-mac

Comment: @Tetsujin I've overviewed it before posting and as you said couldn't find the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that will disable the feature completely on a constant basis, regardless of whether that checkbox to preserve windows is checked or not, the windows will not restore.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "#!/bin/bash" > /tmp/loginfix.sh
echo "rm /Users/*/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow.*" >> /tmp/loginfix.sh
mv /tmp/loginfix.sh /usr/bin/loginfix.sh
chmod +x /usr/bin/loginfix.sh
defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /usr/bin/loginfix.sh
```

To restore default behavior:

```
sudo defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook
```

Full details here:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/25/disable-reopen-windows-when-logging-back-in-in-mac-os-x-lion-completely/

You may also be interested in this:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/18/disable-mac-os-x-lion-resume-window-restore/